# EF Code First Migrations not working to Azure

Tags: .net, entity-framework, azure, entity-framework-migrations

This is frustrating me, and I've been through the questions/answers here several times, I seem to be missing something very basic.  I'm using EF 6 with MVC 5 and SQL Server.  The process as I understand it and am currently following is:

1. Create model and initial migration.
2. Run Update-Database (locally)
3. Deploy to Azure, checking "perform migrations" checkbox.
4. Modify Model
5. Create migration
6. Update-Database (locally)
7. Deploy to Azure, checking "Perform Migrations" checkbox.

It works locally, but I when I deploy to Azure I consistently get:

> "The model backing the '*{contextname}*' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).

If I drop the database, delete all the migrations and create a new "Initial" migration, it re-creates the empty database and my software works.  But I would prefer not to lose all my data, which I was under the impression was the point of the EF migrations.

So what am I doing wrong?

As a side note, in my latest attempt I manually modified the azure database to match the local one and I still get the above error.

Answer (score 2):

Can you run the update-database command pointing to the Azure DB rather than local. Does this error?

You can change the Azure Database manually but the __MigrationHistory table must be in sync with a local one. What I sometimes do, is apply the changes on a local db and then go to the Azure one, mimic these changes then clear out the rows in the Azure Db __MigrationHistory table and copy all the rows from your local __MigrationHistory table after migration has been applied.

This is what Entity Framework (EF) checks to see if Migrations have been applied - would check to see if the number of rows match.

Also note when applying migrations to a table in Azure that contains a large amount of data it generally times out so you end up doing it manually.